# CDT marks std::initalizer_list as error

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

My eclipse cdt marks function definitions and function calls that use initializer_lists as error. This happens both on linux and windows even though the path to the include is set and it seems to find it. Now even though it's just mildly annoying I want to get rid of it.

I suspect I have to tell the cdt something like the -std=c++0x I had to tell the compiler to get initializer lists compiled. Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: The IDE might not be up to the level of C++11 compliance that your compiler is. There is really not that much to do.

Comment: Which toolchain is selected for C/C++ within eclipse ? Check project properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Chain Editor

Comment: I'm on windows now. Tool chain is MinGW GCC. Though I compile at the command line. So it should be used just for the indexer.

Comment: see e.g. this post on the Eclipse forum http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/787571/

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but here are some workaround steps:

1. Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Analysis
2. Select the `Invalid Arguments` item under `Syntax and Semantic Errors`.
3. Click the `Customize Selected...` button.
4. In the `Scope` tab, add the file(s) containing the initialization list syntax to the exclusion patterns.
5. Click OK/Apply/OK.
6. Select the files that show errors, right click > Index > Freshen All Files

The errors should go away then (they did for me).